# How do I store selected checkbox items from list to another list in .net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

ViewModel

```
public IList<SelectListItem> SelectedCases { get; set; } = new List<SelectListItem>();

[DisplayName("Available Cases")]
public IList<SelectListItem> AvailableCases { get; set; } = new List<SelectListItem>();
```

.cshtml page

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.AvailableCases.Count(); i++)
{
     <br />
     <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.AvailableCases[i].Selected" />
     <label asp-for="@Model.AvailableCases[i].Selected">@Model.AvailableCases[i].Text</label>
}
```

While clicking on Save button of this page, I want to get all selected items of AvailableCases to selectedCases list.

I am new to .net core.

Comment: So you only want to pass selected checkbox Text and selected to SelectedCases?

Comment: yes pass selected values to the SelectedCases list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working demo:

Model:

```
public class TestCheckBox {
        public IList<SelectListItem> SelectedCases { get; set; } = new List<SelectListItem>();

        [DisplayName("Available Cases")]
        public IList<SelectListItem> AvailableCases { get; set; } = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult TestBindCheckBox() {
            TestCheckBox t = new TestCheckBox { AvailableCases = new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = "one" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "two" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "three" } } };
            return View(t);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult TestBindCheckBox(TestCheckBox testCheckBox)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
```

CheckBox.cs(ViewComponent):

```
public class CheckBox:ViewComponent
    {
        
        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(TestCheckBox t)
        {
            return View(t);
        }
       
    }
```

Pages/Shared/CheckBox/Default.cshtml:

```
<form method="post" id="myForm">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.AvailableCases.Count(); i++)
    {
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.AvailableCases[i].Selected" />
        <input hidden asp-for="@Model.AvailableCases[i].Text" />
        <label asp-for="@Model.AvailableCases[i].Selected">@Model.AvailableCases[i].Text</label>
    }
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

TestBindCheckBox:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("CheckBox", @Model)
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $('#myForm').submit(function () {
            var count = 0;
            $(":checkbox:checked").each(function () {
                $(this).attr("name", "SelectedCases[" + count + "].Selected");
                $(this).next("input").attr("name", "SelectedCases[" + count + "].Text");
                count++;
            })
            return true; // return false to cancel form action
        });
    </script>

}
```

result:
[image]

Update:
If you are using ViewComponent,only need to use

Comment: I have changed my answer with viewcomponent.And in my answer,I only bind text and selected to SelectedCases,the other data value and disabled , etc are the default values of `SelectListItem`.